# How to export a complete page+resources from a website to jsFiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

I am working on a website (on localhost) with some fancy interactive js and css.
(in fact I am working on an admin UI for a Drupal module)

I would like to share it on jsFiddle, to get feedback from others. However, the website and the UI I am working on depends on plenty of resources: Images, javascript, css..

What would be the easiest way to copy the html + resources to jsFiddle or a similar service?
Maybe with a web archive? Zip?

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy/upload resources to jsfiddle. You have to upload images, css files, or other resources to dropbox or other file hosting services with public access and then access resources via your html code.